# Backbone + RequireJS: Making Collection Persisting?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, requirejs

I'm using Backbone with RequireJS, and my View needs to switch between like, say, 20 collections corresponding to respective RESTful APIs.

The "normal" way handles things fine, except that for each API a new Collection needs to be defined, resulting in a hugely bloated codebase:

**Collection (x 20 times)**

```
define(function(require) {
    var Backbone = require('backbone');

    var c = Backbone.Collection.extend({
        url: '/path/to/api-1'
    });

    return new c();
});
```

**View**

```
define(function(require) {
    var Backbone = require('backbone'),
           c1 = require('./collections/collection-1'),
           ...
           c20 = require('./collections/collection-20');

    var v = Backbone.View.extend({
        /* Some methods to toggle between Collections here */
    });

    return v;
});
```

By only doing `return c;` inside the Collection, and calling `new c({url: /path/to/api-1});` inside the View, I was able to cut down the highly duplicated Collection defines; but now on each `new c();` calls, the APIs will always be poked to retrieve a new copy of data, which is a waste to resources and something I do not want.

Is there any way to make Collections "persistent"? Which better meets all of the criteria below:

- For each API's corresponding Collection, only one `new` is performed;
- Each Collection can be shared/accessed across different Views defined using RequireJS;
- The definition of the Collection can be reused by all APIs;
- The global namespace is not polluted at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a rather hackish solution:

Wrap your **Collection** with another **Model**:

```
define(function(require) {
    var Backbone = require('backbone'),
        m = require('../models/model');

    var wrapper = Backbone.Model.extend({
        initialize: function() {
            var $_path = this.get('path');

            var c = Backbone.Collection.extend({
                model: m,

                url: $_path,

                initialize: function() {
                    this.deferred = this.fetch();
                }
            });

            this.set({
                collection: new c()
            });
        }
    });

    return wrapper;
});
```

Then, define a Cache container:

```
define(function(require) {
    return cache = {};
});
```

Require both the Cache container and the wrapped Collection in your View module:

```
define(function(require) {
    var $ = require('jquery'),
        _ = require('underscore'),
        Backbone = require('backbone'),
        cache = require(cache),
        wrapper = require('../collections/collection');

    var v = Backbone.View.extend({
        render: function($_path) {
            var c = cache[$_path] || cache[$_path] = new wrapper({
                path: $_path
            }).get('collection'));
        } 
        ....
    });

    return v;
});
```

This way you get both the benefits of instantiate new Collections with dynamically-generated `$_path` values, and being able to cache data fetched from your APIs so long the page is not refreshed - implement `localStorage` if you'd like the data to persist through page refreshes.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to make a new file / collection.

You could just do something like this in your view:

```
var collections = [];
collections.push( Backbone.Collection.extend({url: '/path/to/api-1'});
collections.push( Backbone.Collection.extend({url: '/path/to/api-2'});
collections.push( Backbone.Collection.extend({url: '/path/to/api-3'});
```

...

```
collections.push( Backbone.Collection.extend({url: '/path/to/api-20'});

var view1 = Backbone.View.extend( {data:collections} );
var view2 = Backbone.View.extend( {data:collections} );
```

You will then have an array loaded with all your collections

Comment: However, `collections` can't be shared/acceessed by different View modules defined in AMD format, unless it's being made a global object - which is another thing I'd like to avoid.

Comment: They can be instantiated and passes into all views that need them as parameters.

Answer (score 0):

In a similar vein to the other answer, you could have a collections array defined as an AMD module:

**Collections**

```
define(['backbone', 'underscore'], function(Backbone, _) {
    var collections = [];

    var urls = ['/path/to/api-1', '/path/to/api-2', '/path/to/api-3'];

    _(urls).each(function(url) {
        collections.push(Backbone.Collection.extend({
            url: url
        }));
    });

    return collections;
});
```

And your views could use it like this:

**View**

```
define(['Backbone', 'collections'], function(Backbone, collections) {

    var v = Backbone.View.extend({
        /* Some methods to toggle between Collections here */
    });

    return v;
});
```

Comment: The issue is I'd like to retain the flexibility to define `url` on instantiation, so this might not work.