# How do I prevent a method from firing before I receive data from my server?

Tags: javascript, html, backbone.js

So I am using backbonejs to generate a html page base on a data that I receive from google datastore. The problem I'm have is trying to stop my render method from returning before I the data is received.

A little side question: Is it possible to open a window.open() passing in html?

Comment: Do you mean write your html to the window you open with window.open()?

Comment: So I decided to just go with a ajax and not use backbone fetch.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of calling window.open() with html in it (basically you are passing some data), you can open your window by window.open() and after that call your predefined funciton in that window and pass your data (or your HTML) to that function and let it do your job :)

Answer (score 0):

Why fight it? Load up your page with spinners in the areas where the google data will go. When the google data finally comes back, update backbone with that data and render again; this time with the data instead of the spinners.

If you really want to fight it, you can cause jQuery ajax calls to run synchronously with the `async` option. Add `async: false` to the options you are passing in to the ajax call.

[jQuery.ajax() Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Comment: ...but remember that synchronous calls will make your users go crazy ;)

Comment: Indeed. I am in no way endorsing synchronous calls. I prefer to view this kind of situation as a very strong code smell. But it's not possible in every case to re-design a solution.

Comment: I can't do that because currently I generate the page and send it to google conversion api  to make a pdf. Since I it will be sent to google api, its not possible to update the html.

Comment: @PhongLe in that case see the second half of my answer. Passing `async: false` as an option to the backbone call should cause the request to run synchronously.

Comment: @PhongLe well, another way to go would be to have the google data asynchronous ajax callback create the backbone view passing in the google data. Then you would be guaranteed to have the data before render gets called. but i am pretty surprised the async option didn't work. it works for me in version 0.9.2 of backbone.

Answer (score 0):

**In your Collection:**

```
var c = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    url: '/path/to/api',

    initialize: function() {
        this.deferred = this.fetch();
    }
});
```

**In your View:**

```
var v = Backbone.View.extend({
    render: function() {
        c.deferred.done(function() {
            /* Render your View here */
        });
    }
});
```

This is made possible due to `collection.fetch()` returning a jqXHR. More explanations [here](http://quickleft.com/blog/leveraging-deferreds-in-backbonejs).

Comment: How can I add param data to the fetch this way?

Comment: The way I found was to wrap the Collection definition with another Model definition; check http://stackoverflow.com/a/12241854/1530563 for a more thorough explanation.

Comment: I don't think I can accomplish it with the wrapper class without breaking my project. It's gotten really big now.